# How to restric cookies from one domain to another domain

Tags: javascript, adobe, launch

I have a website and in submenu I am navigating to another domain. The problem is what ever the consent preference is selected in domain1 is, inheriting same consent cookies in domain 2.
How to restric domain 1 cookies in domain 2. Tried with Same site setting but no luck any suggestions please

Comment: Are these subdomains of the same parent? Otherwise, there shouldn't be any shared cookies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.